# Wordpress creating additional links

Tags: php, wordpress

[Google SERP Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHB1U.jpg) I have a simple wordpress page template, however when creating a page wordpress is creating two additional pages/links causing 404 and indexed by Google, how can I prevent that?

**Below is the template page code:**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: PackageDetails 
*/
get_header();
global $post;
//echo $post->ID;die;
 ?>
<div class="container hds-custom text-left">
<div class="row">
    <div class="grey-bg clearfix">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();
                    the_content();
                }
            }?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <?php $page_images =& get_children( array ( 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'order' =>  'ASC', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ));
             if ( $page_images ) {
                foreach ($page_images as $image) 
                    {
                        echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full')[0].'" class="img-responsive mt-2 mb-1" alt="'.get_the_title($image->ID).'">';
                    }
                } ?>
             <h2>BOOKING AND RESERVATION (24/7)</h2>
             <p>MOBILE NO: <a href="tel:+13245679">(+132) 13245679</a> / <a href="tel:+12345689">1234566</a></p>
             <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="552" title="Booking &amp; Reservation"]')?>
             <div class="alert alert-warning mt-1 mb-1 clear">
                 Important note / Cancellation / Amendment / Refund policy:
             </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Booking should be made at least 48 hours in advance or subject to availability.</li>
                <li>Trip cancellation / amendment should be informed within 24 hours otherwise 100% Cancellation Charges may apply.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are those two pages? . In that link there is only one. Don't understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: just added an image from Google SERP

Comment: Did u edited old page and changed the url?

Comment: No, haven't edited old page nor changed the URL

Comment: Tried force crawl?

Answer (score 0):

If you have made recent changes what you can try is to forcefully reindex your website. Please check the below url it might be helpful. 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

I don't think it's a problem with php or WordPress.